# Int 21h/ah=39h returns with AX=3 upon directory creation

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, dosbox, create-directory

I'm trying to create a new directory in *DOSBOX*. I'm on Debian, using *MASM* via *DOSBOX*. The code is very simple, but it doesn't work.

I have executed it with the debug, and it returns the error 3 (AX=0003h after execution). According to [this](http://fleder44.net/312/notes/16Files/Index.html), the error is because the path doesn't exists. My *DOSBOX* has the C: drive mounted on the directory where the .asm code is.

I don't understand why I am getting this error. If i run `mkdir C:\nuevo` from the *DOSBOX* command line, it will create the directory `nuevo` without a problem

```
.model small
.stack
.code
  mov dx, offset filepath
  mov ah, 39h
  int 21h
  mov ah, 4ch
  int 21h

  ret
  filepath db "C:\nuevo", 0
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that MASM doesn't treat the character combination `\n` as a newline escape sequence?

Comment: that's a pretty good bet... but it does not treat `\n` as a newline escape sequence... I just checked with the debug, and the `"C:\nuevo"` string is stored just as it reads... i just changed the name of the folder to `C:\asdf`, just to be sure, but the error is the same :( (error 3 on AX)

Comment: And there are no permission issues (i.e. does DOSBox run as a user that has permission to write to the folder that you mounted as C:)?

Comment: yeah, i double checked it... when i create a folder from dosbox, it works just fine, but i can't create it from my asm program, i don't know why :'(.

The error it returns on the AX register, says that the directory where i am trying to create the folder does not exists

Comment: Seems you are creating a DOS EXE. You need to initialize _DS_ register with your data segment. At the top of your code you should have something like `mov ax, @data` `mov ds, ax`.

Comment: OMG, OMG... that works, but i don't really know why XD

could you please put it as an answer? so i can mark my question as answered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating a DOS *EXE* program *DS* and *ES* point to the [DOS PSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix) segment, not your actual data segment. With an *EXE* you need to initialize *DS* so that it points to your own data segment. To do this with *TASM/MASM* you use code like this at the beginning of your program:

```
mov ax, @data 
mov ds, ax
```

This moves the `data` segment value into *AX* and then sets *DS* .

The reason why your program failed to work is because without proper initialization your *DS:DX* combination for `int 21h/ah=39h` was pointing at the wrong memory, and thus the wrong path.

If you were creating a COM program *CS*=*DS*=*ES*  so no setup of the *DS* is required. This is because all the segment registers are initialized to the same 64k segment when your COM program is launched.